# To show $A\implies B$, is that sufficient to show for all $C$ s.t. $C\implies A$ then $C\implies B$

Tags: logic

my question is in the title:

to show $A\implies B$ is it enough to show for any $C$ such that $C\implies A$
we have $C\implies B$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes but that doesn't make it easier since you could choose $C = A$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean $((C\implies A) \implies (C\implies B)) \implies (A\implies B)$?

From the truth table, this is false when A is true, B is false and C is false. Therefore, this formula is *not* true in general.

A nice truth table generator: http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/47/mcclung/index.html

Comment: But this should be *for all* $C$

Comment: It is for all C.

Comment: This is how I interpreted the question as well. If the formula quoted here is true for all $C$ then indeed $A$ implies $B$.

Comment: But this formula is not a tautology. In the case I mention, it is false. As such, we cannot say that it is true in general.

Comment: ...and that, boys and girls, is the difference between "*If some ravens are black then all ravens are black.*" and "*If all ravens are black then all ravens are black.*" :-)

Comment: More explicitly, there is a huge difference between $\forall C, ( P(C) \implies Q )$ and $(\forall C, P(C)) \implies Q$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that was what the OP was talking about.